# Controller tests with authlogic expecting user_sessions table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, authlogic

I'm using [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) (along with [Authlogic RPX](http://github.com/tardate/rails-authlogic-rpx-sample)) in a new Rails 3 application (beta4 , just upgraded to RC).

I cannot get any of my functional tests to pass. Anytime I try to run even the most rudimentary test, I end up with this error:

```
  4) Error:
     test_the_truth(UsersControllerTest):
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: 
     user_sessions: DELETE FROM "user_sessions" WHERE 1=1
```

It doesn't matter which controller I'm testing (even if it's not associated with Authlogic), it seems to expect that my `UserSession` model requires a database table, even though it inherits directly from `Authlogic::Session::Base`

Outside of using the RPX plugin, this is a super-base Authlogic setup, and I do not have this issue running the application itself. Only in the tests.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It appears I was being hamstrung by Rails 3's [backtrace filtering](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/212009). I re-ran my tests to provide a full backtrace:

```
BACKTRACE=foo rake test
```

Turns out the problem was with attempting to load test fixtures for `users_session` that were auto-generated with my classes.